# Get all preceding/following sibling text content

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0, schematron

Consider the following XML:

```
<paratext ID="p34"><bold>pass</bold> <bold>pass</bold></paratext>
<paratext ID="p35"><bold>pass</bold></paratext>
<paratext ID="p36">foo <bold>pass</bold> bar</paratext>
<paratext ID="p37">foo<bold> pass </bold>bar</paratext>
<paratext ID="p38"><bold>fail</bold><bold>fail</bold></paratext>
<paratext ID="p39">foo<bold>fail</bold>bar</paratext>
```

p34 should pass because there is non-alpha between the letters of the bold tags
p35 should pass because there are no alpha chars on the outside of the bold tags
p36 should pass because there is non-alpha between the bold text and other text
p37 should pass because there is non-alpha between the bold text and other text
p38 should fail because there are no alpha chars between the bold alpha chars
p39 should fail because there are no alpha chars between the bold text and "foo" or "bar"

My attempt to do this via schematron has been this:

```
<iso:rule context="//jd:csc|//jd:bold|//jd:ital|//jd:underscore">
 <iso:assert test="   
    string-length(preceding-sibling::text()) = 0
    or      
    matches(substring(preceding-sibling::text(), string-length(preceding-sibling::text())), '[^a-zA-Z]')
    or
    matches(substring(.,1,1), '[^a-zA-Z]')
    ">
    {WS1046} An .alpha character cannot both immediately preceed and follow &lt;<iso:value-of select="name()"/>&gt; tag
 </iso:assert>
 <iso:assert test="  
    string-length(following-sibling::text()) = 0
    or
    matches(substring(following-sibling::text(), 1,1), '[^a-zA-Z]')
    or
    matches(substring(., string-length(.)), '[^a-zA-Z]')
    ">
    {WS1046} An .alpha character cannot both immediately preceed and follow &lt;/<iso:value-of select="name()"/>&gt; tag
 </iso:assert>
</iso:rule>
```

The problem with this is that it only looks at the direct child text nodes of the parent of the current context. As such, p38 would not fail as there are no direct child text nodes. Also, something like `b<foo>bar <bold>pass</bold>` would fail because it would only see the "b" in `preceding-sibling::text()` and would not see the `"foo "`.

I've also tried `::*/text()` instead of `::text()`, but then I run into a similar issue because I only see text within sibling elements and do not get the direct sibling text-nodes. I need to get both things together, does anyone know how?

---

For example, in this xml:

```
<paratext ID="p1">hello <foo>bar</foo> <bold>THIS</bold> <foo>bar</foo>goodbye</paratext>
```

When the context rule hits `<bold>THIS</bold>` and is checking preceding, I would like it to see `"hello bar "` and when checking the following I would like it to see `" bargoodbye"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well with XPath 2.0 (which you seem to use as you use `matches`) you can use:

```
string-join(preceding-sibling::node(), '')
```

to get `"hello bar "`, and:

```
string-join(following-sibling::node(), '')
```

to get `" bargoodbye"`.

The above lines assume you only have element and text nodes as sibling. If there can be comments and/or processing instructions and you want to **ignore** their contents for these rules, you can use:

```
string-join(preceding-sibling::* | preceding-sibling::text(), '')
```